# JQuery: How to get all bottom-most children in a DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

Based on the DOM tree below, I want to get all of the `<p>` element that are the child of every div with `message` as its class and put them all in an array. This will create an array of objects.

Note : `ul` and all of its children in all levels can be added dynamically to the dom at any given time.

How do I do that?

**I have tried**

```
    var messages = $('.rightP').find('li>.message>p');
    $.each(messages,function(){
        console.log(this);
    });
```

but no luck

---

**DOM tree**

```
<ul class="rightP">
    <li>
        <div class="sender">
            <p>David</p>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
           <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="sender">
            <p>Watson</p>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
           <p>yes anything?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
         ....
    </li>
    ...

</ul>
```

Comment: You can get them like this: http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/C79Pb/ - doesn't order them as you haven't given an example of those data attributes

Comment: @scrowler if u had answered, I might have accepted it. Seems like ordering is not that necessary anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used wrong jQuery selector. Replace `$('.rightP').('li>.message>p')` with `$('.message > p')` or you could do it this way.

```
var messages = jQuery('.message > p');

jQuery.each(messages, function (index, elem) {
    var message = jQuery(elem);
    console.log(message.text())
});
```

Here's the [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/umayr/LaumL/).

Answer (score 0):

> $('.rightP').('li>.message>p');

Wrong statement. You should try

> $('.rightP').find('li>.message>p');

etc...

Comment: This was just a typo. Thanks for correcting but you should have just commented on my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all those like bellow

```
var messages = $('.rightP').find('li>.message>p');
$.each(messages,function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```